# requiring a custom gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I forked https://github.com/evolve75/RubyTree and made a few changes for usage in an application. I also added a rubytree.gemspec (which was not present in the original repo) in order to install it with bundler using a Gemfile in my application:

```
gem 'rubytree', :git => 'git@github.com:anthonylebrun/RubyTree.git'
```

I do a `bundle install` in my app and everything goes smoothly but I'm not able to

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'tree'
```

and just have it work. Instead I get:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- tree
```

So I suspect I may be setting up paths wrong? I'm no gemspec pro, I just threw it together by looking at another gem. Here it is:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.platform    = Gem::Platform::RUBY
  s.name        = 'rubytree'
  s.version     = '0.8.1'
  s.summary     = 'Tree data structure'
  s.description = 'RubyTree allows you to create and manipulate tree structures in ruby'

  s.required_ruby_version     = '>= 1.8.7'
  s.required_rubygems_version = ">= 1.3.6"

  s.author            = 'Anupam Sengupta'
  s.email             = 'anupamsg@gmail.com'
  s.homepage          = 'http://rubytree.rubyforge.org/'

  s.files        = ['lib/tree.rb']
  s.require_path = ['lib']

end
```

Any ideas? If there's anything I can clarify, let me know too!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'tree'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
require 'rubytree'
```

as well?